# Catching status code from redirect in Slim v3

Tags: php, redirect, slim, http-status-codes

I have a view that sends a form to another route and this checks that all data in form is correct but if aren't, this route (/check) must redirect to the view with the form (/form) with the code XXX so I can catch this code and I can know where is the problem (incorrect data, form not filled ...).
The problem is that `$response->getStatusCode();` also returns `200`.

Routes show like this:

```
$app->get('/form', function($request, $response, $arguments) {  
    $error = array("error" => false);
    echo $response->getStatusCode(); //Always print 200

    if($response->getStatusCode() == XXX) 
        $error["error"] = true;

    return $this->view->render($response, "form.php", $error);
});

$app->post('/check', function($request, $response, $arguments) {
    return $response->withHeader('Location', '/form')->withStatus(403);    
});
```

Comment: did you noticed that you redirect to ``/access`` in ``/check`` and not to ``/form``

Comment: Both form and access load the same view. But yes, I didn't noticed about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The responsecode is from the current response so it is default 200, when you not change it in the current route. 
The response object get created in every request, so it doesn't save the values you entered before.

You could take it like that

- Client request `/check`
- Server response with a redirect and 403
- Client redirects and requests `/form`
- <-- here you are now, you cannot know the 403 status code in the redirect.

You may use url parameters like `?error=true`, a session or cookies.

OR:

Dont redirect and add the post also to `/form` and validate it there.

Comment: Mmm, ok, I'll use query params, but where can I use the status code if the page which redirects don't take it? What's its purpose? Thank you

Comment: Basically there are for notifying the user/browser, if there are any errors.